# IntDef annotation in Android

Tags: android, annotations

In Android, there is a recommendation that developers should not use `enum`. Instead of `enum`, Android supports some annotations, like `@IntDef`.

I tried this annotation is a simple project. My code looks like this:

```
@IntDef({APPLE, BANANA})
public @interface Fruit {
}

public static final int APPLE = 1;
public static final int BANANA = 2;

private @Fruit int mFruit;
```

If I try to set variable `mFruit` to 6 for example, I see the message that it must be one of `APPLE` or `BANANA`. This is fine, it works great.

When I paste this code to my second application and I try to set variable to different value than `APPLE` or `BANANA`, it works and there is no warning message and I am able to build application.

So, my question is: is there any way how can I disable or enable support of this annotation? What can cause this different behavior, that some project supports it and some project don't? I am using the same version of Android Studio for both projects.

Comment: did you add library dependency? Did you use same android studio version?  
Also it's shouldn't fail build anyways, its only warning in lint

Comment: @orium Yes, I use the same version of AS. In the second project, there is no warning, simply it seams that this annotation is totally ignored...

Comment: did you mark you field in second app with @Fruit ?

Comment: Yes, I used totally the same code.

Comment: seems like ide bug, try restart)

Comment: I tried. Also I tried it yesterday and today the same case. I do not know what is wrong...some lint settings, maybe?

Comment: what gradle plugin version you use?

Comment: I am using gradle:1.3.0

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to explicitly set [retention policy.](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html) Look at the [official Android IntDef example](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/IntDef.html), where retention policy is set to @Retention(SOURCE)